# An asynchronous nsurlconnection in a popup view in ios7

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, popup

I am creating an asynchronous `NSURLconnection` in a popup view in ios.
To implement the asynchronous `NSURLconnection` I implement the methods of the `NSURLDelegate`.
The problem occurs when the user taps outside the popup view and the view is dismissed.
leaving the `nsurlconnection` callbacks and other actions inside the view incomplete.
How can I assure that the actions inside the popup complete inspite of the dismissal of the view?
I tried putting an activity indicator inside the popup view till the actions are completed, but even then a tap outside the popup view dismisses the view.
I dont want the user to be left with an inactive app till actions are completed, instead I want the actions to be completed in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send an asynchronous connection you can use this methods.

**GET REQUEST**

```
-(void)placeGetRequest:(NSString *)action withHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error))ourBlock {

     NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", URL_API, action];

     NSURL *urlUsers = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
     NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlUsers];

     [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:ourBlock];
}
```

**POST REQUEST**

```
-(void)placePostRequest:(NSString *)action withData:(NSDictionary *)dataToSend withHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error))ourBlock {
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", URL_API, action];
    NSLog(urlString);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    // Creamos el JSON desde el data
    NSError *error;

    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dataToSend options:0 error:&error];

    NSString *jsonString;
    if (! jsonData) {
        NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
    } else {
        jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[jsonString UTF8String] length:[jsonString lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setHTTPBody: requestData];

        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:ourBlock];
    }
}
```

**EXAMPLE OF USE**

```
- (void) getMyMethod:(NSString *)myParam1
            myParam2:(NSString *)myParam2
            myParam3:(NSString *)myParam3
            calledBy:(id)calledBy
         withSuccess:(SEL)successCallback
          andFailure:(SEL)failureCallback{
    [self placeGetRequest:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"api/myMethod?myParam1=%@&myParam2=%@&myParam3=%@",myParam1, myParam2, myParam3]
                 withHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *rawData, NSError *error) {

                     NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
                     NSInteger code = [httpResponse statusCode];
                     NSLog(@"%ld", (long)code);

                     if (code == 0){
                         // error
                     } else if (!(code >= 200 && code < 300) && !(code == 500)) {
                         NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:rawData
                                                                  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                         NSLog(@"ERROR (%ld): %@", (long)code, string);
                         [calledBy performSelector:failureCallback withObject:string];
                     } else {

                         // If you receive a JSON
                         NSMutableDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:rawData options:0 error:nil];
                         // If you receive an Array
                         // NSArray *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:rawData options:0 error:nil];

                         // If you receive a string
                         // NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:rawData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                         [calledBy performSelector:successCallback withObject:result];
                     }
                 }];
```

}

**CALL YOU MUST DO IN YOUR VIEW/CONTROLLER/ETC**

```
(...)

[api getMyMethod:myParam1Value myParam2:myParam2Value myParam3:myParam3Value calledBy:self withSuccess:@selector(getMyMethodDidEnd:) andFailure:@selector(getMyMethodFailureFailure:)];

(...)

// Don't forget to set your callbacks functions or callbacks will do your app crash

-(void)getMyMethodDidEnd:(id)result{
    // your actions with the result
    // ...
}

-(void)getMyMethodFailure:(id)result{
    // your actions with the result
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the dismissal of popup view when tapping out side u need to implement this delegate method

```
 - (BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
   {
      return NO;
   }
```

dismiss it by using the action

```
 - (void)someAction
   {

      //check the operations are completed 
      .....
      .....
      [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
  }
```

Comment: But I want the user to be able to dismiss the popup and still be able to complete the NSURLConnection delegate callbacks and other operations part of the popup class.